# Highlight my navbar menu items whenever I scroll through that section? Only using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I currently have my nav menu items highlighted whenever I click them, but I want the entire section in the HTML to have a highlighted background, so when the user is scrolling through the website, it will automatically highlight the nav menu item according to the whichever section they are scrolling through

Here is an example on codepen that I'm trying to achieve with my code
https://codepen.io/joxmar/pen/NqqMEg

Here is my current landing page in Jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hzg02k3n/

As you can see from my jsfiddle, the links get highlights when I click, but I need it to become active whenever I scroll over the section.

Below my current HTML code

```
<header class="page__header">
      <nav class="navbar__menu">
        <!-- Navigation starts as empty UL that will be populated with JS -->
        <ul id="navbar__list"></ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
      <header class="main__hero">
        <h1>Landing Page</h1>
      </header>
<section id="section1" data-nav="Section 1" class="active">
        <div class="landing__container">
          <h2>Section 1</h2>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi
            fermentum metus faucibus lectus pharetra dapibus. Suspendisse
            potenti. Aenean aliquam elementum mi, ac euismod augue. Donec eget
            lacinia ex. Phasellus imperdiet porta orci eget mollis. Sed
            convallis sollicit
          </p>

          <p>
            Aliquam a convallis justo. Vivamus venenatis, erat eget pulvinar
            gravida, ipsum l
          </p>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section id="section2" data-nav="Section 2">
        <div class="landing__container">
          <h2>Section 2</h2>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi
            fermentum metus faucibus lectus pharetra dapibus. Suspendisse
            potenti. Aenean aliquam elementum mi, ac euismod augue. Donec eget
            lacinia ex. Phasellus imperdiet porta orci eget mollis. Sed
            convallis s
          </p>

          <p>
            Aliquam a convallis justo. Vivamus venenatis, erat eget pulvinar
            gravida, ipsum l
          </p>
        </div>
      </section>
```

I have up to 4 sections, but this just shows the first two.

Here is my Javascript that I used to create the navbar

```
const navMenu = document.querySelectorAll("section");
const navList = document.getElementById("navbar__list");
const items = ["Section 1", "Section 2", "Section 3", "Section 4"];

//Build the nav
items.forEach((item, i) => {
  const el = document.createElement("a");
  el.innerText = item;
  el.classList.add("menu-items");
  el.setAttribute("id", `menu-${i + 1}`);
  el.href = `#section${i + 1}`;
  navList.appendChild(el);

  const li = document.createElement("li");
  li.classList.add("menu-list");
  li.appendChild(el);
  li.setAttribute("id", `${i + 1}`);
  // Append the list item to the list
  navList.appendChild(li);
});

//Make Nav Active when Clicked and scrolls down to section
document.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  let active = document.querySelector(".menu-list.active");
  if (active) active.classList.remove("active");
  if (event.target.classList.contains("menu-list")) {
    event.target.classList.add("active");
    window.location.href = "#section" + event.target.id;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just utilize the [`mouseover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseover_event) and [`mouseout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseout_event) events!

Here is a small example & [here is a JS Fiddle as well](https://jsfiddle.net/Parasin/aerfsu28/2/):

```js
const navMenu = document.querySelectorAll("section");
const navList = document.getElementById("navbar__list");
const items = ["Section 1", "Section 2", "Section 3", "Section 4"];
let lastId;
let last_known_scroll_position = 0;
let ticking = false;

//Build the nav
items.forEach((item, i) => {
  const li = document.createElement("li");
  const el = document.createElement("a");
  el.innerText = item;
  el.classList.add("menu-items");
  el.setAttribute("id", `menu-${i + 1}`);
  el.href = `#section${i + 1}`;

  el.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    const href = e.target.getAttribute("href"),
      offsetTop = href === "#" ? 0 : e.target.offsetTop - topMenuHeight + 1;
    const scrollOptions = {
      scrollIntoView: true,
      behavior: "smooth"
    };
    e.target.scrollIntoView(scrollOptions);
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  navList.appendChild(li);
  li.appendChild(el);
});

const topMenu = document.getElementById("navbar__list");
const topMenuHeight = topMenu.offsetHeight + 1;
const menuItems = document.querySelectorAll(".menu-items");
const scrollItems = document.querySelectorAll(".sec");

//Make Nav Active when Clicked and scrolls down to section
document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  let active = document.querySelector(".active");
  if (active) {
    active.classList.remove("active");
  }
  if (event.target.classList.contains("menu-items")) {
    event.target.classList.add("active");
  }
});

// Bind to scroll
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  // Get container scroll position
  const container = document.querySelector(".container");
  let fromTop = window.pageYOffset + topMenuHeight + 40;

  // Get id of current scroll item
  let cur = [];

  [...scrollItems].map(function(item) {
    if (item.offsetTop < fromTop) {
      cur.push(item);
    }
  });

  // Get the id of the current element
  cur = cur[cur.length - 1];
  let id = cur ? cur.id : "";

  if (lastId !== id) {
    lastId = id;

    menuItems.forEach(function(elem, index) {
      elem.classList.remove("active");
      const filteredItems = [...menuItems].filter(elem => elem.getAttribute("href") === `#${id}`);
      filteredItems[0].classList.add("active");
    });
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
}

#navbar__list {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #55443D;
  display: block;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#navbar__list ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#navbar__list li {
  display: table-cell;
}

#navbar__list li a {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#navbar__list li a:hover {
  color: #dc5c26;
}

#navbar__list li a .active {
  color: #F38A8A;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #F38A8A;
}

.active {
  color: #F38A8A;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #F38A8A;
}

.sec {
  height: 50vh;
  display: block;
}

.sec h2 {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

#section1 {
  background-color: green;
}

#section2 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#section3 {
  background-color: blue;
}

#section4 {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<ul id="navbar__list"></ul>

<section class="container">
  <div id="section1" class="sec">
    <h2>Section 1</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="section2" class="sec">
    <h2>Section 2</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="section3" class="sec">
    <h2>Section 3</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="section4" class="sec">
    <h2>Section 4</h2>
  </div>
</section>
```

#### Edit: [This is the working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Parasin/6zytvs09/41/) using your code

Comment: Will that achieve the same effect as this codepen? https://codepen.io/joxmar/pen/NqqMEg

I also want the navbar section the be highlight whenever I scroll down to that section, even if my mouse is not hovering over the section

Comment: @Brian Standby! Updating the answer

Comment: I updated the Javascript because I had to add an id to the li, but here's a JSfiddle file if it helps https://jsfiddle.net/hzg02k3n/

Comment: It's not working yet :/ I need it to become active when I scroll over the section, not when I click. It is only highlighted when I click the menu item.

Comment: Got it, i'll work specifically on the scroll stuff then

Comment: @Brian Ok I got it! Check the JS at the bottom. I added a `window` scroll listener that is working :)

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how you did it, so I can implement it in my code, but I noticed you made a different design in HTML and contained things completely different to the way I labeled my sections. How would I add that to my current jsfiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/hzg02k3n/


Also, the last section 4 doesn't get highlighted.

I just need the window.addEventListener("scroll", function () for my specific page because I'm not sure how to code it properly using the correct tags and functions

Comment: Working on updating your fiddle

Comment: I checked it out and I couldn't tell what was different? You know when you click the Section menu item and it turns green with the black background? I'm trying to achieve that same green text and black background just by scrolling down without clicking. So, if I click section 1 for example, then scroll down to the bottom, section 4 should become active and turn green and black without me having to click it.

Comment: @Brian see the link on the bottom of my answer, sorry for the confusion

Comment: @Brian did you get it working, or did this resolve your issue?

Comment: Glad that I could help :) be sure to mark the answer as correct if it solved the issue